# azure blob file loading concept

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to load read csv from blob and modify as per per requirement and rewriting  again but getting
error
**for i in reader:
#print(i)
if i[0]=='PO no.' :
i[1]="Dum"
lst.append(','.join(i)+"\n")
#dt.writelines(','.join(i)+"\n")
#blob_client.upload_blob('||'.join(i))

```
      flag=True
 #  print"============================================")
   elif flag == True :
     lst.append(','.join(i)+"\n")
     # dt.writelines(','.join(i)+"\n")
    # blob_client.upload_blob('||'.join(i))
   else:
      pass
#with open('abc.csv','rb') as csvdt:
  # blob_client.upload_blob(csvdt)
blob_client.upload_blob(lst)**

i want load list but getting error
```

Comment: Hey Ravi, could you check your formatting please? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide the error message?

Comment: blob_client.upload_blob(csvdt)
Uploading to Azure Storage as blob:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\script2.py", line 57, in <module>
    blob_client.upload_blob(csvdt)
  File "C:\Users\Ravindra.Kudache\ana\lib\site-packages\azure\core\tracing\decorator.py", line 83, in wrapper_use_tracer
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ravindra.Kudache\ana\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_blob_client.py", line 527, in upload_blob
    return upload_block_blob(**options)